# WordPress: Can't get posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get posts using the following code:

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();
if ( have_posts() ) {

while ( have_posts() ) {

    the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php}
}
?>
```

But nothing is displayed and if I do a var_dump on the_post() am still getting null.
Ps: I've created two posts on the wp-admin panel means that they really exist in the db.

Comment: what about var_dump of `have_posts()` ?

Comment: Y U reset the query?

Comment: `wp_reset_query();` use it after while loop

Comment: it returns "true"...

Comment: @TamilSelvan Same to same, have_posts is returning true, but i still can't get the posts..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what really happened, but I resolved the issue by removing all pages I've created before and then create them again...
Now, everything works fine.